# Zend Pagination changing value injection

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

In Zend_Paginator

I am trying to change one of the values of the paginator object after the database result

I loop through the paginator - get the item an then sent the rank

However this is not carrying forward to the view pagination and rank is NULL

```
    // Loop through the results and get the users Rank
    foreach ($paginator as $k => $v) {

        $rowSet       = $paginator->getItem($i);
        $rowSet->rank = $table->getRanking($rowSet->score);

        echo $rowSet->first_name . '<br />';
        echo $rowSet->rank . '<br />';

        $i++;
    }

    $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
```

Comment: is the getRanking function returning null? also what is the value for $rowSet->score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Paginator iterator like this:

```
foreach ( $paginator as &$item )
{
    $item->rank = $table->getRanking($item->score);
}
```

Please note the &$item which makes the $item an reference to the actual $item not the copy of the $item.

Answer (score 0):

That is really not the way you are supposed to use foreach loops. You do not even use $k or $v inside the foreach.
[link text](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Question was about Paginator not how to construct foreach loops.

Comment: @IanWarner right but your code was broken and I poited it out. 3 years ago lol. You are entitled to your opinion of course.